# Null values from viewmodel when trying to upload file with data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I'm trying to create a view that lets a user upload an Office-file along with a class that holds URL, Type etc. I'm currently using this viewmodel:

```
public class ServiceFileUploadViewModel
{
    public FileUpload File { get; set; }
    public IList<Service> AvalibleServices { get; set; }
    public IList<Service> SelectedServices { get; set; }
    public PostedServices PostedServices { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload { get; set; }

}
public class PostedServices
{
    public int[] ServicesIds { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using an extension called "[CheckBoxListFor](http://mvccbl.com/)" that creates a list of checkboxes, that will link the file to a specific Service.

This is my view with the form:

```
@model ServiceFileUploadViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("_Upload", "ServiceCatalog", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

{
<div>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
</div>

<div>
    Dokumenttyp
</div>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.File.DocumentType)
</div>

<div>
    @Html.CheckBoxListFor(m => m.PostedServices.ServicesIds,
                        m => m.AvalibleServices,
                        entity => entity.Id,
                        entity => entity.Name,
                        m => m.SelectedServices,
                        Position.Vertical)
</div>

<div>
    <label>Visningsalternativ</label>
</div>
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.File.IsPrivate, "true", true) Interninformation
</div>
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.File.IsPrivate, "false", false) Kundinformation
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Ladda upp" />
}
```

My problem is that when I set a breakpoint inside my _Upload Action in my Controller, all values (file, FileUpload-Class) are null except the "PostedServices" array which contains the Services selected in Checkboxlist.

I've been trying to figure this out but with no success. Any ideas to why my form doesn't map correctly to my viewmodel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload` property will be `null` because you have named the input "file". It needs to be

```
<input type="file" name="FileUpload" />.
```

This also means that `FileUpload File` will be null on post back because you try to bind the value of the uploaded file to typeof `FileUpload` (which of course fails - hence it's `null`).

Note: You haven't posted your `FileUpload` class so can't be sure there are not other issues as well.

Note also that you should remove the 3rd parameter from `@Html.RadioButtonFor()`. Your using a strongly typed helper which means the selected button will be based on the value of `IsPrivate`

Comment: That was it! Thanks alot for the fast and accurate response!